# Visibility issue with a private Scala method

Tags: scala, methods, call, private

I have the following snippet of Scala code, part of a larger source file with more classes, which comprises of private field, method and public method:

```
class Grid {

  private val cells = Vector(
    Vector(new Cell, new Cell, new Cell),
    Vector(new Cell, new Cell, new Cell),
    Vector(new Cell, new Cell, new Cell)
  )



 private def tranpose(grid:Vector[Vector[Cell]]) : Vector[Vector[Cell]] = {
    val newgrid = Vector(
      Vector(grid(0)(0), grid(1)(0), grid(2)(0)),
      Vector(grid(0)(1), grid(1)(1), grid(2)(1)),
      Vector(grid(0)(2), grid(1)(2), grid(2)(2))
      )
    newgrid
     }

  // Determine winner or draw
    def wins(symbol:Char):Boolean  = {
       val fullvec = Vector(symbol, symbol, symbol)
       for(r<-cells)
          if(r.equals(fullvec))
            true

        // Transpose the grid into a new one and make the same check again
        val transpgrid = transpose(cells)
        for(r<-transpgrid)
           if(r.equals(fullvec))
             true

        // Now check diagonals
        val maindiag = Vector(cells(0)(0), cells(1)(1), cells(2)(2))
        val seconddiag = Vector(cells(0)(2), cells(1)(1), cells(2)(0))
        if(maindiag.equals(fullvec) || seconddiag.equals(fullvec)) 
           true
         false
    }
```

In the line of code `val transpgrid = transpose(cells)` inside the `wins` method, `scala` gives me the following message:

```
jasonfil@hp ~/AtomicScala/examples $ scala TicTacToe.scala 
TicTacToe.scala:69: error: not found: value transpose
    val transpgrid = transpose(cells)
```

I have tried adding the keyword `this` in front of the call to `transpose`, yet I have had no luck. I'm new to the language and presume I'm making some kind of mistake at call-time.

// Edit: I have since flagged this post for moderator approval and deletion, since it's obvious that I wasn't paying enough attention in creating the minimal example (obvious typo). However, I have since realized that another thing wrong with this code of mine is the liberal non-use of the "return" keyword from areas of the code that are **clearly** not the last line of their respective methods. This caused me a lot of heartache yesterday, yet I learnt from said heartache.

Comment: If you don't chose to delete the question, maybe you could change the title. "How to detect spelling errors etc." There ought to be a plugin for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot delete my own question because it has already been answered to. I did, however, flag it for moderator intervention. Only reason for which this happened is because I'm using Sublime and a terminal instead of an IDE until I figure out all the command-line options to the programs `scala` and `scalac`. Once that is done, I will naturally move on to an appropriate Scala IDE. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Me, too. I'll make a note somewhere of the idea for a plugin to assist with spelling errors like `"abc".sze` that relies on an implicit. An IDE could offer a quick fix; I don't know if they do that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error - `private def tranpose` should be `private def transpose`

Comment: Well, this should go down in Guiness World Records somehow. Thanks, marked solved.